# Thumbor + tc_aws - Error on save result

Tags: python, thumbor

I'm trying install Thumbor with tc_aws and I have a problem with result storage.

The image can not be saved in result bucket and Thumbor return error that cannot be debugged.

Someone can help me?

Start command: sudo thumbor --log-level debug --port=9000 --conf=/etc/thumbor/thumbor.conf

The Thumbor URL is: http://thumbor.centraldoevento.com.br:9000/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs=/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg

Config file is:

```
TC_AWS_REGION='us-west-2' # AWS Region

TC_AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET='images-centraldoevento' # S3 bucket for Storage
TC_AWS_STORAGE_ROOT_PATH='' # S3 path prefix for Storage bucket

TC_AWS_LOADER_BUCKET='images-centraldoevento' #S3 bucket for loader
TC_AWS_LOADER_ROOT_PATH='' # S3 path prefix for Loader bucket

TC_AWS_RESULT_STORAGE_BUCKET='thumbor-centraldoevento' # S3 bucket for result Storage
TC_AWS_RESULT_STORAGE_ROOT_PATH='result' # S3 path prefix for Result storage bucket

# put data into S3 using the Server Side Encryption functionality to
# encrypt data at rest in S3
# https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2011/10/04/amazon-s3-announces-server-side-encryption-support/
TC_AWS_STORAGE_SSE=False

# put data into S3 with Reduced Redundancy
# https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2010/05/19/announcing-amazon-s3-reduced-redundancy-storage/
TC_AWS_STORAGE_RRS=False


# Enable HTTP Loader as well?
# This would allow you to load watermarks in over your images dynamically through a URI
# E.g.
# http://your-thumbor.com/unsafe/filters:watermark(http://example.com/watermark.png,0,0,50)/s3_bucket/photo.jpg
TC_AWS_ENABLE_HTTP_LOADER=False

TC_AWS_ALLOWED_BUCKETS=False # List of allowed bucket to be requested
TC_AWS_STORE_METADATA=False # Store result with metadata (for instance content-type)


################################### Logging ####################################

## Log Format to be used by thumbor when writing log messages.
## Defaults to: %(asctime)s %(name)s:%(levelname)s %(message)s
#THUMBOR_LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s %(name)s:%(levelname)s %(message)s'

## Date Format to be used by thumbor when writing log messages.
## Defaults to: %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
#THUMBOR_LOG_DATE_FORMAT = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'

################################################################################


################################### Imaging ####################################

## Max width in pixels for images read or generated by thumbor
## Defaults to: 0
#MAX_WIDTH = 0

## Max height in pixels for images read or generated by thumbor
## Defaults to: 0
#MAX_HEIGHT = 0

## Min width in pixels for images read or generated by thumbor
## Defaults to: 1
#MIN_WIDTH = 1

## Min width in pixels for images read or generated by thumbor
## Defaults to: 1
#MIN_HEIGHT = 1

## Allowed domains for the http loader to download. These are regular
## expressions.
## Defaults to: []
#ALLOWED_SOURCES = #    [
#    ]


## Quality index used for generated JPEG images
## Defaults to: 80
#QUALITY = 80

## Max AGE sent as a header for the image served by thumbor in seconds
## Defaults to: 86400
#MAX_AGE = 86400

## Indicates the Max AGE header in seconds for temporary images (images that
## haven't been detected yet)
## Defaults to: 0
#MAX_AGE_TEMP_IMAGE = 0

## Indicates whether thumbor should rotate images that have an Orientation EXIF
## header
## Defaults to: False
#RESPECT_ORIENTATION = False

## Indicates whether thumbor should enable the EXPERIMENTAL support for animated
## gifs.
## Defaults to: True
#ALLOW_ANIMATED_GIFS = True

################################################################################


################################ Extensibility #################################

## The loader thumbor should use to load the original image. This must be the
## full name of a python module (python must be able to import it)
## Defaults to: thumbor.loaders.http_loader
#LOADER = 'thumbor.loaders.http_loader'
LOADER = 'tc_aws.loaders.s3_loader'


## The file storage thumbor should use to store original images. This must be the
## full name of a python module (python must be able to import it)
## Defaults to: thumbor.storages.file_storage
#STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.file_storage'
STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.no_storage'


## The result storage thumbor should use to store generated images. This must be
## the full name of a python module (python must be able to import it)
## Defaults to: None
#RESULT_STORAGE = None
RESULT_STORAGE = 'tc_aws.result_storages.s3_storage'

## The imaging engine thumbor should use to perform image operations. This must
## be the full name of a python module (python must be able to import it)
## Defaults to: thumbor.engines.pil
#ENGINE = 'thumbor.engines.pil'

################################################################################


################################### Security ###################################

## The security key thumbor uses to sign image URLs
## Defaults to: MY_SECURE_KEY
#SECURITY_KEY = '3dwekYgsys1BxXPi4Xphof39zX034m38'

## Indicates if the /unsafe URL should be available
## Defaults to: True
#ALLOW_UNSAFE_URL = True

## Indicates if encrypted (old style) URLs should be allowed
## Defaults to: True
#ALLOW_OLD_URLS = True

################################################################################


################################# File Loader ##################################

## The root path where the File Loader will try to find images
## Defaults to: /tmp
#FILE_LOADER_ROOT_PATH = '/tmp'

################################################################################


################################# File Storage #################################

## Expiration in seconds for the images in the File Storage. Defaults to one
## month
## Defaults to: 2592000
#STORAGE_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 2592000

## Indicates whether thumbor should store the signing key for each image in the
## file storage. This allows the key to be changed and old images to still be
## properly found
## Defaults to: False
#STORES_CRYPTO_KEY_FOR_EACH_IMAGE = False

## The root path where the File Storage will try to find images
## Defaults to: /var/folders/th/z6vmj34j1gngpvwl5fg5t9440000gp/T/thumbor/storage
#FILE_STORAGE_ROOT_PATH = '/var/folders/th/z6vmj34j1gngpvwl5fg5t9440000gp/T/thumbor/storage'

################################################################################


#################################### Upload ####################################

## Max size in Kb for images uploaded to thumbor
## Aliases: MAX_SIZE
## Defaults to: 0
#UPLOAD_MAX_SIZE = 0

## Indicates whether thumbor should enable File uploads
## Aliases: ENABLE_ORIGINAL_PHOTO_UPLOAD
## Defaults to: False
#UPLOAD_ENABLED = False

## The type of storage to store uploaded images with
## Aliases: ORIGINAL_PHOTO_STORAGE
## Defaults to: thumbor.storages.file_storage
#UPLOAD_PHOTO_STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.file_storage'

## Indicates whether image deletion should be allowed
## Aliases: ALLOW_ORIGINAL_PHOTO_DELETION
## Defaults to: False
#UPLOAD_DELETE_ALLOWED = False

## Indicates whether image overwrite should be allowed
## Aliases: ALLOW_ORIGINAL_PHOTO_PUTTING
## Defaults to: False
#UPLOAD_PUT_ALLOWED = False

## Default filename for image uploaded
## Defaults to: image
#UPLOAD_DEFAULT_FILENAME = 'image'

################################################################################


############################### MongoDB Storage ################################

## MongoDB storage server host
## Defaults to: localhost
#MONGO_STORAGE_SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'

## MongoDB storage server port
## Defaults to: 27017
#MONGO_STORAGE_SERVER_PORT = 27017

## MongoDB storage server database name
## Defaults to: thumbor
#MONGO_STORAGE_SERVER_DB = 'thumbor'

## MongoDB storage image collection
## Defaults to: images
#MONGO_STORAGE_SERVER_COLLECTION = 'images'

################################################################################


################################ Redis Storage #################################

## Redis storage server host
## Defaults to: localhost
#REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'

## Redis storage server port
## Defaults to: 6379
#REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_PORT = 6379

## Redis storage database index
## Defaults to: 0
#REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_DB = 0

## Redis storage server password
## Defaults to: None
#REDIS_STORAGE_SERVER_PASSWORD = None

################################################################################


############################### Memcache Storage ###############################

## List of Memcache storage server hosts
## Defaults to: ['localhost:11211']
#MEMCACHE_STORAGE_SERVERS = #    [
#        'localhost:11211',
#    ]


################################################################################


################################ Mixed Storage #################################

## Mixed Storage file storage. This must be the full name of a python module
## (python must be able to import it)
## Defaults to: thumbor.storages.no_storage
#MIXED_STORAGE_FILE_STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.no_storage'

## Mixed Storage signing key storage. This must be the full name of a python
## module (python must be able to import it)
## Defaults to: thumbor.storages.no_storage
#MIXED_STORAGE_CRYPTO_STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.no_storage'

## Mixed Storage detector information storage. This must be the full name of a
## python module (python must be able to import it)
## Defaults to: thumbor.storages.no_storage
#MIXED_STORAGE_DETECTOR_STORAGE = 'thumbor.storages.no_storage'

################################################################################


##################################### Meta #####################################

## The callback function name that should be used by the META route for JSONP
## access
## Defaults to: None
#META_CALLBACK_NAME = None

################################################################################


################################## Detection ###################################

## List of detectors that thumbor should use to find faces and/or features. All
## of them must be full names of python modules (python must be able to import
## it)
## Defaults to: []
#DETECTORS = #    [
#    ]


## The cascade file that opencv will use to detect faces
## Defaults to: haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml
#FACE_DETECTOR_CASCADE_FILE = 'haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml'

################################################################################


################################### Filters ####################################

## List of filters that thumbor will allow to be used in generated images. All of
## them must be full names of python modules (python must be able to import
## it)
## Defaults to: []
#FILTERS = #    [
#    ]





################################ Result Storage ################################

## Expiration in seconds of generated images in the result storage
## Defaults to: 0
#RESULT_STORAGE_EXPIRATION_SECONDS = 0

## Path where the Result storage will store generated images
## Defaults to: /var/folders/th/z6vmj34j1gngpvwl5fg5t9440000gp/T/thumbor/result_storage
#RESULT_STORAGE_FILE_STORAGE_ROOT_PATH = '/var/folders/th/z6vmj34j1gngpvwl5fg5t9440000gp/T/thumbor/result_storage'

## Indicates whether unsafe requests should also be stored in the Result Storage
## Defaults to: False
#RESULT_STORAGE_STORES_UNSAFE = False




############################ Queued Redis Detector #############################

## Server host for the queued redis detector
## Defaults to: localhost
#REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_HOST = 'localhost'

## Server port for the queued redis detector
## Defaults to: 6379
#REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_PORT = 6379

## Server database index for the queued redis detector
## Defaults to: 0
#REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_DB = 0

## Server password for the queued redis detector
## Defaults to: None
#REDIS_QUEUE_SERVER_PASSWORD = None

################################################################################


############################# Queued SQS Detector ##############################

## AWS key id
## Defaults to: None
#SQS_QUEUE_KEY_ID = None

## AWS key secret
## Defaults to: None
#SQS_QUEUE_KEY_SECRET = None

## AWS SQS region
## Defaults to: us-east-1
#SQS_QUEUE_REGION = 'us-east-1'


#################################### Errors ####################################

## This configuration indicates whether thumbor should use a custom error
## handler.
## Defaults to: False
#USE_CUSTOM_ERROR_HANDLING = False

## Error reporting module. Needs to contain a class called ErrorHandler with a
## handle_error(context, handler, exception) method.
## Defaults to: thumbor.error_handlers.sentry
#ERROR_HANDLER_MODULE = 'thumbor.error_handlers.sentry'

################################################################################


############################### Errors - Sentry ################################

## Sentry thumbor project dsn. i.e.: http://5a63d58ae7b94f1dab3dee740b301d6a:73ee
## a45d3e8649239a973087e8f21f98@localhost:9000/2
## Defaults to: 
#SENTRY_DSN_URL = ''

################################################################################
```

Console is:

```
ubuntu@ip-172-31-37-226:~$ sudo thumbor --log-level debug --port=9000 --conf=/etc/thumbor/thumbor.conf
2016-05-23 18:17:25 root:DEBUG thumbor running at 0.0.0.0:9000
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.credentials:DEBUG Skipping environment variable credential check because profile name was explicitly set.
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.credentials:DEBUG Looking for credentials via: env
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.credentials:DEBUG Looking for credentials via: assume-role
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.credentials:DEBUG Looking for credentials via: shared-credentials-file
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.credentials:INFO Found credentials in shared credentials file: ~/.aws/credentials
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.loaders:DEBUG Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/data/endpoints.json
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.loaders:DEBUG Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/data/s3/2006-03-01/service-2.json
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.loaders:DEBUG Loading JSON file: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/botocore/data/_retry.json
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.client:DEBUG Registering retry handlers for service: s3
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7fc54c2a6398>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7fc54c2a2b18>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.client:DEBUG The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.endpoint:DEBUG Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG Cleaning key: UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs=/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG Cleansed key: UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs=/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-parameter-build.s3.GetObject: calling handler <function sse_md5 at 0x7fc54c2c8d70>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-parameter-build.s3.GetObject: calling handler <function validate_bucket_name at 0x7fc54c2c8cf8>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 tornado_botocore.base:DEBUG Making request for OperationModel(name=GetObject) (verify_ssl=True) with params: {'body': '', 'url': u'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/thumbor-centraldoevento/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs%3D/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'Botocore/1.4.22 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-74-generic'}, 'query_string': {}, 'url_path': u'/thumbor-centraldoevento/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs%3D/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg', 'method': u'GET'}
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event request-created.s3.GetObject: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7fc549ff7c90>>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-sign.s3.GetObject: calling handler <function fix_s3_host at 0x7fc54c7f2c08>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.utils:DEBUG Checking for DNS compatible bucket for: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/thumbor-centraldoevento/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs%3D/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.utils:DEBUG URI updated to: https://thumbor-centraldoevento.s3.amazonaws.com/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs%3D/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.auth:DEBUG Calculating signature using hmacv1 auth.
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.auth:DEBUG HTTP request method: GET
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.auth:DEBUG StringToSign:
GET


Mon, 23 May 2016 18:17:31 GMT
/thumbor-centraldoevento/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs%3D/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.parsers:DEBUG Response headers: <tornado.httputil.HTTPHeaders object at 0x7fc549fb2c10>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.parsers:DEBUG Response body:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message><Key>UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs=/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg</Key><RequestId>12939AAD027FDF0C</RequestId><HostId>11ijwYI+YqYsGp2Wl/6o9ES1sB/aWNWFkH53PEq+dkKn+j5jCuQ8yAZfpwo3y7ylpYohZzUlGsM=</HostId></Error>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG METRICS: timing: result_storage.incoming_time:131
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG METRICS: inc: result_storage.miss:1
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG METRICS: inc: storage.miss:1
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.client:DEBUG Registering retry handlers for service: s3
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7fc54c2a6398>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7fc54c2a2b18>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.client:DEBUG The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.endpoint:DEBUG Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG Cleaning key: Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG Cleansed key: Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-parameter-build.s3.GetObject: calling handler <function sse_md5 at 0x7fc54c2c8d70>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-parameter-build.s3.GetObject: calling handler <function validate_bucket_name at 0x7fc54c2c8cf8>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 tornado_botocore.base:DEBUG Making request for OperationModel(name=GetObject) (verify_ssl=True) with params: {'body': '', 'url': u'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images-centraldoevento/Koala.jpg', 'headers': {'User-Agent': 'Botocore/1.4.22 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-74-generic'}, 'query_string': {}, 'url_path': u'/images-centraldoevento/Koala.jpg', 'method': u'GET'}
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event request-created.s3.GetObject: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7fc549fb2c10>>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-sign.s3.GetObject: calling handler <function fix_s3_host at 0x7fc54c7f2c08>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.utils:DEBUG Checking for DNS compatible bucket for: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/images-centraldoevento/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.utils:DEBUG URI updated to: https://images-centraldoevento.s3.amazonaws.com/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.auth:DEBUG Calculating signature using hmacv1 auth.
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.auth:DEBUG HTTP request method: GET
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.auth:DEBUG StringToSign:
GET


Mon, 23 May 2016 18:17:31 GMT
/images-centraldoevento/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.parsers:DEBUG Response headers: <tornado.httputil.HTTPHeaders object at 0x7fc549698790>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.parsers:DEBUG Response body:
<botocore.response.StreamingBody object at 0x7fc54a138c10>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG No image format specified. Retrieving from the image extension: .jpg.
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG Content Type of image/jpeg detected.
2016-05-23 18:17:31 tornado.access:INFO 200 GET /UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs=/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg (187.5.184.32) 729.83ms
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG Cleaning key: UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs=/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 thumbor:DEBUG Cleansed key: UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs=/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.client:DEBUG Registering retry handlers for service: s3
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_post at 0x7fc54c2a6398>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event creating-client-class.s3: calling handler <function add_generate_presigned_url at 0x7fc54c2a2b18>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.client:DEBUG The s3 config key is not a dictionary type, ignoring its value of: None
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.endpoint:DEBUG Setting s3 timeout as (60, 60)
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function validate_ascii_metadata at 0x7fc54c2c46e0>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function sse_md5 at 0x7fc54c2c8d70>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function convert_body_to_file_like_object at 0x7fc54c2c4c80>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-parameter-build.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function validate_bucket_name at 0x7fc54c2c8cf8>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 tornado_botocore.base:DEBUG Making request for OperationModel(name=PutObject) (verify_ssl=True) with params: {'body': <StringIO.StringIO instance at 0x7fc549fcf4d0>, 'url': u'https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/thumbor-centraldoevento/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs%3D/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg', 'headers': {u'x-amz-meta-Server': 'Thumbor/6.0.1', u'x-amz-storage-class': 'STANDARD', u'x-amz-meta-Cache-Control': 'max-age=86400,public', u'x-amz-meta-Date': 'Mon, 23 May 2016 18:17:31 GMT', 'User-Agent': 'Botocore/1.4.22 Python/2.7.6 Linux/3.13.0-74-generic', u'x-amz-meta-Expires': 'Tue, 24 May 2016 18:17:31 GMT', u'x-amz-meta-Content-Type': 'image/jpeg'}, 'query_string': {}, 'url_path': u'/thumbor-centraldoevento/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs%3D/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg', 'method': u'PUT'}
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event request-created.s3.PutObject: calling handler <bound method RequestSigner.handler of <botocore.signers.RequestSigner object at 0x7fc54e598890>>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.hooks:DEBUG Event before-sign.s3.PutObject: calling handler <function fix_s3_host at 0x7fc54c7f2c08>
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.utils:DEBUG Checking for DNS compatible bucket for: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/thumbor-centraldoevento/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs%3D/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.utils:DEBUG URI updated to: https://thumbor-centraldoevento.s3.amazonaws.com/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs%3D/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.auth:DEBUG Calculating signature using hmacv1 auth.
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.auth:DEBUG HTTP request method: PUT
2016-05-23 18:17:31 botocore.auth:DEBUG StringToSign:
PUT


Mon, 23 May 2016 18:17:31 GMT
x-amz-meta-cache-control:max-age=86400,public
x-amz-meta-content-type:image/jpeg
x-amz-meta-date:Mon, 23 May 2016 18:17:31 GMT
x-amz-meta-expires:Tue, 24 May 2016 18:17:31 GMT
x-amz-meta-server:Thumbor/6.0.1
x-amz-storage-class:STANDARD
/thumbor-centraldoevento/UgCH96k1fNiFS-fR_Dgh2B-Hujs%3D/122x101/smart/Koala.jpg
2016-05-23 18:17:31 tornado.application:ERROR Exception in callback <functools.partial object at 0x7fc549670100>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 600, in _run_callback
    ret = callback()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/stack_context.py", line 275, in null_wrapper
    return fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/ioloop.py", line 615, in <lambda>
    self.add_future(ret, lambda f: f.result())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/gen.py", line 282, in wrapper
    yielded = next(result)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/thumbor/handlers/__init__.py", line 371, in save_to_result_storage
    yield gen.maybe_future(context.modules.result_storage.put(results))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 473, in wrapper
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 461, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tc_aws/result_storages/s3_storage.py", line 41, in put
    super(Storage, self).set(bytes, path, callback=callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 473, in wrapper
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 461, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tc_aws/aws/storage.py", line 79, in set
    callback=callback,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 473, in wrapper
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 232, in result
    raise_exc_info(self._exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/concurrent.py", line 461, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tc_aws/aws/bucket.py", line 100, in put
    session.call(**args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado_botocore/base.py", line 97, in call
    return self._make_api_call(operation_name=self.operation, api_params=kwargs, callback=callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado_botocore/base.py", line 60, in _make_api_call
    operation_model=operation_model, request_dict=request_dict, callback=callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado_botocore/base.py", line 54, in _make_request
    request_dict=request_dict, operation_model=operation_model, callback=callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado_botocore/base.py", line 40, in _send_request
    validate_cert=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpclient.py", line 430, in __init__
    self.body = body
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/httpclient.py", line 475, in body
    self._body = utf8(value)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tornado/escape.py", line 203, in utf8
    "Expected bytes, unicode, or None; got %r" % type(value)
TypeError: Expected bytes, unicode, or None; got <type 'instance>
```